# Tracable anonymous recurring records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an application where users fill out surveys on a regular basis.

Surveys are sent via e-mail and need to be semi-tracable, meaning, that I need to follow what kind of question categories are sent to each user on each survey. Right now after answering the survey, answers are saved in a separate table and any association to a particular user is removed to guarantee anonymity.

What I would like to achieve is a way where it is not possible to map any anwser with a particular user BUT it is possible to get all answers that any one user has submitted. We want to do this for analysis purposes to track how user's answers change over time, but at the same time preserve complete anonymity on a database level.

Users fill out surveys using several devices so private key storing on their device is not an option.

Application is written in Rails with PostgreSQL, but the solution can also involve other languages if it is not possible in ruby.

Comment: do users use some identifier before filling the survey?.. you can't guess user and be sure it was him. so you need an identifier. for anonimity you need to have no relation between identifier and real name(photo,email,any real info)

Comment: There is a relation between user an survey object. But once "Submit" button is pressed, the answers are saved on a separate table with no relation to the user. My guess is that Some kind of smart "hashing" could be used.

Comment: you surely can hash anything, but if you destroy relation between hashing and original user - how user can return?..

Comment: Can the solution ask users to reference a confirmation code from a previous email?

Comment: @AbeVoelker No. It should not involve users doing anything.

Comment: Hmm I was thinking generate a UUID, sign it with MessageEncryptor, and email that to the user (and don't store anything in the DB). If a user could reference a previous email you could create a linked list, but I don't know how to do it if they can't reference a previous email w/o compromising user -> survey relation 

Comment: Given the fact that anonymous and traceable is a oxymoron. The only way I can see to provide analytics of this nature overtime is to have some functional mechanism for scoring an answer based on your own criteria scale. You could then score the answer and store it with the user and the question but the answer itself would remain detached. Obviously on a large scale this scoring mechanism is an of itself would be difficult to write and extremely opinionated but if the objective is simply to see the change over time the score would be directly based on a known factor which could work.

Comment: Maybe try asking on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple solutions would be feeding a fixed set of user data to a hash function to calculate an identifier for that user, save it into the separate table along with the answers.

This way you'll be able to gather all submissions per user but there will be no relation to the user record.

A drawback is that if you would still want it you can trace a user by calculating all the hashes for your "users" table and associating it with the "answers" table. Unless you give up control over either "users" or "answers" entity to another team/business unit etc.

Comment: Yes, this was my first Idea but the drawback you mentioned is exactly why I can't use it. Because you can reverse it.

Comment: It comes down to the fact that until you are in control over the system that manages (and marks) answers you will always be able to build association. Would be nice to have a solution though!